# What's the ideal method for populating a drop down list via AJAX (AJAJ?) in razor/jquery?

Tags: c#, jquery, razor

So I've got this `@Html.DropDownList("Thangs")` inside of a hidden div. When the user clicks a link to expose the div, I want to make an AJAX call to grab the things that should be in the list. It will be returned as JSON. How would I bind the incoming JSON objects as name/values into the DropDownList using jQuery?

Comment: Just a comment, when considering AJAX and jQuery solutions Razor, ASPX or even PHP doesn't enter into the equation. By the time jQuery kicks in the page has already been rendered so the engine that provided the HTML is irrelevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have not posted any sample json so

```
...
success:function(data){

$("#SelectList").empty(); //remove previous items in the ddl

//iterate the json
$.each(data,function(key,val){
  $("<option/>",{value:key,text:val}).appendTo("#SelectList");
  });
}
```

here is the [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/EG8Ee/5/)